Recover Plasma Applets after upgrade to 24.10
After upgrading to 24.10, some Plasma applications crash or fail to load and the default panel is displayed incorrectly, for example the classic clock is displayed as Unknown.

How can I fix these issues?

Kubuntu 24.10 uses KDE Plasma 6.1, Qt6 which is newer, and using newer Q toolkit, newer version of KDE Frameworks etc, and some old plasma applets/widgets intended for KDE Plasma 5/Qt5 may no longer operate (or differ), so replacing them with newer KDE Plasma 6/Qt6 widgets maybe better. For help with apps, you'll need to be specific as we don't know if you're using a KDE 6/Qt6/KF6 app, or legacy app for older software stack (used in prior releases).
